# TYPO3 EXT tx_news und typoscript USER multi integrations

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

i input multi integrations tx_news elements on my site, via TS:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html

it works fine!
but the ext loaded the full tx_news libs again and again on the Frontpage!
That even where the news page will not be used / loaded in FE
even where the dough is not needed, the ext is loaded... :/
Thus, the website has become very slow.

how do I include multiple elements?

in the AdminPanel see i the loaded FE code
"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap" is 280 in teh code and "Bootstrap" is over600 in the code

I comment out the info, then the website loads normally.
what can i do?
Thanks!

Comment: okay the first part is, dont load the libs in FLUID variables ! There go in global Website, the TYPO3 rendering build all lib´s on all sites....now i load the libs via <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.XXX" /> ! and the pagespeed is better! from 60.000MS to 1.500ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a rewording of your comment. Using a code like this

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
 variables {
    fo = USER
    fo {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

will execute the `USER` (or any other cObj), no matter if is then used in the template at all. Therefore always a TS like this

```
lib.fo = USER
lib.fo {
  ...
}
```

and integrate it into the template by using `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.fo" />`

Please mark the answer as solution, thanks