# backend_layout with colPos other than 0,1,2 not working

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, fluid-styled-content

I have setup a distribution which also provides PageTS for backend_layouts.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig(
'<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:'. $_EXTKEY .'/Configuration/TSconfig/Page.txt">');
```

and this is how content is assigned with TypoScript

```
page.20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.20 {
  partialRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Partials
  layoutRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Layouts

  file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
  file.stdWrap.cObject {
      key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
      key.override.field = backend_layout

      # das default template 2spaltig
      default = TEXT
      default.value = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/Landing.html

      # das LandingPage backend layout 3 spaltig
      pagets__1 = TEXT
      pagets__1.value = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/Landing.html


      # das 2spaltige backend layout
      pagets__2 = TEXT
      pagets__2.value = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/Default.html

  }

  variables {
      kopf < styles.content.get
      kopf.select.where=colPos=5
      contentLeft < styles.content.get
      contentLeft.select.where=colPos=1
      contentMain < styles.content.get
      contentMain.select.where=colPos=0
      contentRight < styles.content.get
      contentRight.select.where=colPos=2
   }
 }
```

Problem is:

No matter what I do I dont get colPos 5 rendered in Frontend. It seems like only colPos 0(main),1(left),2(right) are allowed. 
But the Content is saved to database and has a 5 in the colpos field.
And no result whatsoever for colPos 5.

I use fluid_styled_content only - no css_styled_content.
And it is included before my distribution in Template Setup.

**UPDATE**
this is on nginx with php7.0-fpm & mysql 5.6

forgot to to say that the kopf variable is used in a Partial, so it is exactly the same problem as stated here
[partial variable problem](http://www.typo3.net/forum/thematik/zeige/thema/122786/?tx_typo3forum_pi1%5BshowForm%5D=0&cHash=b8afe77d8dbae43da1a3a1f9b6b476a1)

Comment: solution was as discribed in the given link with the use of arguments:{contentTop: contentTop} inside the partial. Funny I could not find this documented anywhere

Comment: Just a comment: Don't use the variables section for that as that is a drawback regarding performance. Read about it at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38843416/2389552

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble getting markers to work with **select.where=colPos=5** I ended up using the longer lookup variant with the table as a parameter.

```
KOPF = CONTENT
KOPF {
   table = tt_content
   select {
       orderBy = sorting
       where = colPos = 5
   }
}
```